# obvious rpy2 usage throws an unsupported operand type(s) exception

Tags: python, r, rpy2, operand

I am getting some unexpected behaviour with rypy2:

```
 ma / robjects.r.rowSums(ma)
```

where ma is a matrix

throws an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Matrix' and 'FloatVector'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python operators might differ from R [operators](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#operators).

A self-contained example is not provided with the question, but this should work

```
ma.ro / robjects.r.rowSums(ma)
```

Comment: This one worked!   What I do not understand is ma is already an r object, why it needed a blessing from .ro ?  Anyway thanks Igautier!